# (Open) LDAP authentication - superuser not available on client

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ldap, authentication

I'm still arguing with LDAP authentication. Now I have a server running openldap in centos, some account and a client that can use that directory to log on.

The issue I have is that I'm no longer able to login as superuser on ldap client: typing `su root` and entering the superuser password of the client I'm no longer able to  log in (I get wrong credentials).

According to client's `/etc/passwd` I have one (and only one) root account (gid =0 , uid =0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future use the issue was that in `nssswitch.conf` I had ldap switch before files one and root account wasn't available on ldap server.

So I just had to enter 3 times a wrong password to be able to use local accounts (other option was to invert files and ldap giving preference to local auth, but it's not the case as I want user's log-in to be tracked on ldap server)